# stdin/stdout for command launched from a shell

Tags: linux, shell

a very basic question about character echoed when typed into a terminal.

Consider for example a Linux system on which the cat command is issued from a shell (e.g. bash). Now, from my understanding, the shell spawns a process to execute cat executable and, at this stage, cat stdin and stdout are attached to terminal.

Now the question: Does the shell continue to receive character from the terminal (eventually echoing them) or just the spawned process (executing cat) only ?

Answer (score 2):

The shell will pass the file descriptors (fd's) to the subprocess (`cat`) but will also transfer control. So as long as `cat` is running, the shell doesn't do anything, doesn't receive input, and so on.

Technically the shell `fork`s and `exec`s the subprocess in the child fork, then `wait`s for the subprocess to finish. Once that is done, the shell will wait for more input (allowing you to type a next command), and then runs that, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The foreground process receives input from the terminal.  Whichever process is in the foreground is the only one to receive it (unless it contains internal logic to pass it on to another process).

Answer (score 1):

The shell does not receive the characters, only the foreground process. But that's not the whole story.

What you type is first processed by the terminal device driver. The driver has two modes of working: canonical and non-canonical. In the canonical mode, which is used when you run `cat`, the driver echos characters as you type them and accumulates lines of text. This allows some basic editing, like using backspace to delete what you typed. `cat` does not get to see what you type until you press enter or Ctrl-D.

In the non-canonical mode the terminal just passes characters to the process without interpretation or modification: this is how full-screen apps work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies,

I've done an "experiment" forcing off terminal (putty) local echo. Launching cat into a shell and sending characters I can see

~ # cat

hello

hello

~ #

for each character I type ('h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o') i can see each one on the terminal screen and then hitting Return key I can see the entire word "hello".

Now, IUUC, the first character occurrences on the screen are due to the 'canonical mode' terminal device driver (driver echos them). Then just when i hit Return the accumulated line 'hello' is "seen" by cat and sent from it to the stdout (the terminal screen again)

does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense. As you note: the echoing of the separate characters is caused by your local terminal. Program `cat` is started (by default) in line-buffered mode, so it'll see your "hello" once you hit ENTER. Then, if you quit `cat` using ^D, the shell will receive anything you type next.

Comment: here for "local terminal" do you mean the terminal device driver (e.g. /dev/pty/0) and not the terminal Putty software?

Comment: Since you wrote that you forced Putty into local-echo mode, that's what I meant. When I snoop what the libc call `read` returns and how it's invoked, I see Bash requesting characters one by one, but I see `cat` in line-buffered mode; so `read` is requested to get a longer buffer. In my case (MacOSX) `cat` asks `read` to fetch 131072 characters from fd 0 (stdin); `read` then  returns that 6 characters are seen (hello plus a newline). If you want to snoop such libc calls: I've put up a short blogpost on http://kubat.nl/pages/blogaria/310.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear but Putty (running on a different PC) is forced OFF about local-echo mode

Comment: Aah, the plot thickens. Sorry for missing that. In that case I can only see as an explanation that the individual characters are echoed-back by the device driver on the Linux box. I can't think of anything else; because it's a fact that `cat` will only see your `hello` once you hit enter and not before; so `cat` itself is never capable of echoing-back separate characters.